# Error when encoding an array to JSON

Tags: php, json

```
echo json_encode($testArray);
```

The thing is, it encodes every array element the way I want except the last one. Take a look at what I get:

```
[
 {
 "x": "..",
 "x": "..",
 "x": "..",
 }
]"x": "..","x": "..","x": "
```

As you can see, the last element format is just wrong. Its outside Json object and the format is messed up. Not sure what could cause this. I checked array (which I pass for encoding) and its fine. Any ideas?

Comment: em. Try json)encode($testArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)

Comment: @mcklayin Didnt help. :/

Comment: What is the real given array? plz show. And what is the only return from the function? And what says `json_last_error();`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Comment: I suspect it encodes everything correctly but your data contains non-printable characters that, when printed on the terminal, produce unexpected effects. A [`CR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`\r`) is the usual suspect for the layout you presented in the question.